# How can I prove this finite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^m \frac{i}{2^i} = 2-\frac{(m+2)}{2^m},\forall m \in \mathbb N$$

Comment: You may assume it is correct and use $f(m+1)=f(m)+\frac{m+1}{2^{m+1}}=2-\frac{(m+2)}{2^m}+\frac{m+1}{2^{m+1}}=2-\frac{(m+1)+2}{2^{m+1}}$

Comment: I would rewrite it as a double summation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a dirty trick. Start with:

$\begin{align}
\frac{1 - z^{m + 1}}{1 - z}
   &= \sum_{0 \le k \le m} z^k \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z}
   &= \sum_{0 \le k \le m} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} z^k \\
\frac{1 - z^{m + 1}}{(1 - z)^2} - \frac{(m + 1) z^m}{1 - z}
   &= \sum_{0 \le k \le m} k z^{k - 1}
\end{align}$

Replace $z \mapsto 1/2$ and simplify. Your result falls out.

Answer (score 0):

Say $S = \sum_\limits{i=0}^m \frac{i}{2^i} = \sum_\limits{i=1}^m \frac{i}{2^i} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_\limits{i=2}^m \frac{i}{2^i}$

Hence we can say that $\frac{1}{2}S = \sum_\limits{i=1}^m \frac{i}{2^{i+1}} = \sum_\limits{i=2}^m \frac{i-1}{2^i}$

Therefore we have by subtracting the $2$ equations,

$$\begin{align} & S-\frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_\limits{i=2}^m \frac{i}{2^i} - (\sum_\limits{i=2}^m \frac{i-1}{2^i}) \\ &
\frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_\limits{i=2}^m \frac{1}{2^i} \\ &
\frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} \\ &
S = 1 + 2-\frac{1}{2^{m-2}} \end{align}$$

Hope you can simplify this.

Comment: I can't see how to simplify your result to get in the equality proposed in my question.